# Beginner to Fourier series, stuck on an exercise.

Tags: fourier-series

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ9RL.png) is the function I need to make a Fourier series on, I know where to start, but I get confused along the way and I don't know in general how to "finish up" a Fourier series.

My own solution so far so you can follow my thoughts, used variables etc:
[page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7kqk.png)
[page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5cZm.png)

Hope my handwriting is readable and thank you in advance!

Since the quality of the images aren't good enough, I'll just write it out on here:
$\tilde{f}_k = \int_{-5}^{5} f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$

$\tilde{f}_k = \int_{-5}^{0} 0e^{-ikx}dx + \int_{0}^{5} 3e^{-ikx}dx$

Integrating this, I got:

$\tilde{f}_k = \frac{1}{ik}(3-3e^{-5ik})$

for k = 0 I got $\tilde{f_{0}} = \frac{3}{2}$

After this it gets fuzzy for me for what exactly I need to do, I filled in the formula but the steps after this become weird and unclear. It's kinda different in each example I've seen.

The solution to this problem should be:

$f(x) = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{6}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}sin(\frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{5})$

Comment: Where did you find a camera with 300x400 resolution ?:)

Comment: Yeah, can’t read that.

Comment: Sorry, it's as you can see my phone camera, but it's pretty dark in here with bad lighting, didn't know the quality was this bad!

Comment: Tried recreating the images, and they look clear on my phone and on messenger where I sent them to myself, but when I add them on here the quality just drops

Comment: Try using MathJax to detail your solutions? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference